# Oracle how to address column in PL/SQL FOR LOOP by it's position instead of column name

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there a way to address column by it's position in PL/SQL, something like this

```
BEGIN
FOR r IN (SELECT * FROM table)
LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r.(1));
END LOOP;
END;
```

I tried both bracket types but always get

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following
```

I also tried BULK COLECT INTO with table of varray but then I get

```
PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements
```

And if I declare table with %ROWTYPE and bulk it then it seems to behave the same way as the normal loop.

I tried to look into documentation but couldn't find any example of this scenario.

Comment: PL/SQL is statically typed and record datatype has fixed number of attributes, so it is not required (and doesn't make much sence) to access them by index. What you may try to implement is to turn your pivot table into flat table by using `unpivot` (possibly with dynamic SQL) and then access rows by index.

Answer (score 2):

Using the DBMS_SQL package and the COLUMN_VALUE procedure: but that's a lot of work... probably overkilling for your actual needs: you have to open a sys_refcursor for the query, convert it into a  cursor number with DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER, collect the descriptions of the columns with DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS and loop on the column count and fetch the value with DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE into a specific variable according to its type...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but that sounds really complicated ... in the end I gave up and created an varray and manually assign each column to it and proceeded with that instead as that enabled the work I need it originally for

Answer (score 0):

In general, no. Oracle does not support accessing records by position; only by identifier.

---

You can approach the problem slightly differently and, instead of using `SELECT *`, you can explicitly list the columns to select and give them numeric column aliases:

```sql
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT dummy AS "1" FROM DUAL)
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r."1");
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

You are still referring to the columns by name; only now their names are the "numeric" aliases.

*Note: Personally, I would stick to using the column names and not try to find work-arounds to use positions as positions can change if columns are deleted from the table.*

Comment: that is unfortunately not a valid solution in my case, I need to work with that table as if it was a matrix and run multiple loops on it addressing the columns by position via variable to solve a math problem, so I really need a way to address those columns by their position not by string alias in form of number

Comment: @Baker That appears to be an XY-problem. Instead of trying to get PL/SQL to do something that the syntax does not support (i.e. accessing records by position) why don't you address the actual problem of working on the matrix as there is probably a solution that can be implemented in SQL which will be much more efficient than trying to use PL/SQL.

Comment: I also prefer to solve problems by an SQL query  but in this case I haven't found a feasible solution with it's limitation and PL/SQL offered a nice and quick method ... well in a case that syntax would actually work, but I will try to work around it somehow

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a matrix in PL/SQL you could define one as an indexed table of an indexed table of whatever data type you're dealing with, something like:

```
type t_row is table of varchar2(1) index by pls_integer;
type t_tab is table of t_row index by pls_integer;
l_matrix t_tab;
```

The tricky part is populating it. DBMS_SQL is certainly one approach, but partly for fun, you could use XML. The [DBMS_XMLGEN package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_XMLGEN.html) lets you run a query and get the results back as an XML document with a ROWSET root node. You can then count the ROW nodes under that, and assuming there are any, count the nodes within the first ROW - which gives the matrix dimensions.

You can then use nested loops to populate the matrix, and once done, you can refer to an element as for example `l_matrix(3)(2)`.

This is a working example, where the table being queried has values that are all a single character, for simplicity; you would need to change the matrix definition to handle the data you expect.

```
DECLARE
  -- elements of matrix need to be data type and size suitable for your data
  type t_row is table of varchar2(1) index by pls_integer;
  type t_tab is table of t_row index by pls_integer;
  l_matrix t_tab;
  l_xml xmltype;
  l_rows pls_integer;
  l_cols pls_integer;
BEGIN
  l_xml := dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('SELECT * FROM your_table');

  SELECT XMLQuery('count(/ROWSET/ROW)'
    PASSING l_xml
    RETURNING CONTENT).getnumberval()
  INTO l_rows
  FROM DUAL;

  IF l_rows = 0 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('No data');
    RETURN;
  END IF;

  SELECT XMLQuery('count(/ROWSET/ROW[1]/*)'
    PASSING l_xml
    RETURNING CONTENT).getnumberval()
  INTO l_cols
  FROM DUAL;

  dbms_output.put_line('Rows: ' || l_rows || ' Cols: ' || l_cols);

  -- populate matrix
  FOR i IN 1..l_rows LOOP
    FOR j in 1..l_cols LOOP
      l_matrix(i)(j) := l_xml.extract('/ROWSET/ROW[' || i || ']/*[' || j || ']/text()').getstringval();
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;

  -- refer to a specific element
  dbms_output.put_line('Element 3,2 should be H; is actually: ' || l_matrix(3)(2));

  -- display all elements as list
  FOR i IN 1..l_matrix.COUNT LOOP
    FOR j IN 1..l_matrix(i).COUNT LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line('Row ' || i || ' col ' || j || ': ' || l_matrix(i)(j));
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;

  -- display all elements as grid
  FOR i IN 1..l_matrix.COUNT LOOP
    FOR j IN 1..l_matrix(i).COUNT LOOP
      IF j > 0 THEN
        dbms_output.put(' ');
      END IF;
      -- format/pad real data to align it; simple here with single-char values
      dbms_output.put(l_matrix(i)(j));
    END LOOP;
    dbms_output.new_line;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

With my sample table that outputs:

```
Rows: 4 Cols: 3
Element 3,2 should be H; is actually: H
Row 1 col 1: A
Row 1 col 2: B
Row 1 col 3: C
Row 2 col 1: D
Row 2 col 2: E
Row 2 col 3: F
Row 3 col 1: G
Row 3 col 2: H
Row 3 col 3: I
Row 4 col 1: J
Row 4 col 2: K
Row 4 col 3: L
 A B C
 D E F
 G H I
 J K L
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AsQ6btzB)

---

As @astenx said in a comment, [you can use JSON](https://dbfiddle.uk/kif1B8_o) instead of XML; which would allow you to populate the matrix [like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/DHF3e2sj).

That has raised something else I'd overlooked. My dummy table doesn't have an ID column or an obvious way of ordering the results. For the JSON version I used rownum, but in both that and the original query the order of the rows (in the result set, and thus in the matrix) is currently indeterminate. You need to have a column you can `order by` in the query, or some other way to determine the sequence of rows.

Comment: For 19c and above `JSON_OBJECT(*)` and subsequent `cross apply` is possibly more flexible way to do the same without serialization of everything into one big XML. https://dbfiddle.uk/kif1B8_o